# Проблема с find_package(...)

Tags: cmake

У меня есть собранная библиотека в дебаг конфигурации, для библиотек используются "d" постфиксы, а в xxxConfig.cmake (автоматически сгенерирован) в инструкциях поиска библиотек используются их имена без постфикса. Соответственно, find_package(...) не может найти библиотеку. Что можно сделать "малой кровью", чтобы find_package заработал?

Comment: на вскидку я бы сказал, что правильным решением было бы сделать, чтобы `xxxConfig.cmake` возвращал правильную библиотеку уже с суффиксом...

Answer (score 0):

Можно, в качестве решения проблемы, собирать ваши библиотеки (по прежнему дебажные) без постфикса. Постфиксы и префиксы определяются в `cmake` глобальными переменными, так что достаточно просто переопределить переменную `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` - установите её равной `CMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX`.